# How to add a document inside a transaction

Tags: firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I need to create a document inside a transaction.
The transaction object doesn't have the add function, probably because it would create multiple documents in case the `Firestore` retry the transaction.

The only way i can think is to use `GUID` as document id, but they make very long indexes to lookup.
Is there any way around? Another approach?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be too concerned about the length of a document ID.  I don't think you'll find that performance will suffer if you use a GUID for an ID.  If you're concerned about size, only you can compute about how much of your storage is consumed by IDs.

If you want to limit the size of a random document ID, you can simply generate your own random data and convert that to a string that follows the rules for Firestore document IDs.  It could be something as simple as generating a X number of random letters and concatenating them.

Comment: transaction.set command have some optional parameters like merge. Do you know, as google advocate, of other possible options? here the only info i find https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction.  If it was possible to tell the function to throw an error if the document already exists, like an sql duplicate validation, that would be great.

Comment: If you have a question that's different than the original, please ask it separately.

Comment: My idea of using a duplicate error if possible goes along with your suggestion. Generating random numbers can, sometimes, generate duplicates. If Firestore could somehow prevent from overriding a existent document, all that would be needed is pass the error to the user and let him try again. Another round from the user, another id generated, so the collisions would then been handled.